# How do I create a Rules component for merging multiple field items into one?

Tags: 7, rules, views

I have a "Notes" field on the user. A text area that allows unlimited number of values. I need to merge all of them into just one and delete the others. How do I create a rules component to do this via VBO?

[image]

Comment: Do you have to do it once or every time a node is saved/updated?

Comment: I want to create a component so I can run it manually anytime using VBO.